# Gradient Opacity doesn't work (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

My app has a text with Gradient on a canvas and I move it around&change the Opacity

```
textblock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(
    Color.FromArgb((Byte)opacitiycounter, 255, 255, 0));
```

That works great- but for SolidColorBrush. The challange I got myself into was to change the opacity of a given Gradient:

```
public Points(TextBlock t, GradientBrush color) {
    color.Opacity = opacitiycounter;
    t.Foreground = color;
}
```

The opacity function doesn't seem to work and I can't find another way that I can control the given Gradient Opacity, do I need to create entire new Gradient each time with the old values and change the alpha at each point? if thats the case how do I even copy a gradient?

edit:
I'm trying to edit existing gradient dynamically in WPF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Gradient Brush Fade WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294250/linear-gradient-brush-fade-wpf)

Comment: @Freggar that solves one of the problems of changing the gradient alpha dynamically but I still don't know how to use the given gradient and change the alpha for it\duplicate the colors of the given gradient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The value of the Opacity property is expressed as a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

So this should work:

```
color.Opacity = (double)opacitycounter / 255;
```

Comment: That works! I feel stupid for that sorry. However, I encounter another problem- now all the texts with the gradient change opacity the same (as they point to the same gradient), is there a way to duplicate\copy gradient to a new gradient? EDIT: found out there is a clone function nevermind thanks!